# How can I get this php to return the entire column of an sql db

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a db for an entire column of data, but can't seem to get back more than the first row.

What I have so far is:

```
$medicationItem = array();
$medicationItemSql = "SELECT medication FROM medication";
$medicationItemObj = mysqli_query($connection, $medicationItemSql);
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($medicationItemObj, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo count($row);
}
```

It's not my intention to just get the number of rows, I just have that there to see how many it was returning and it kept spitting out 1.

When I run the sql at cmd line I get back the full result. 6 items from 6 individual rows. Is `mysqli_fetch_array()` not designed to do this?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches one row from `$medicationItemObj`, So use it in a loop or do what is in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give this a try:

```
$results = mysqli_fetch_all($medicationItemObj, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had a hard time understanding your question but i guess you are looking for this.

```
$medicationItem = array();
$medicationItemSql = "SELECT medication FROM medication";
$medicationItemObj = mysqli_query($connection, $medicationItemSql);

if($row = mysqli_num_rows($medicationItemObj))
{
    echo $row;
}
```

Or

```
$medicationItem = array();
$medicationItemSql = "SELECT medication FROM medication";
$medicationItemObj = mysqli_query($connection, $medicationItemSql);
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($medicationItemObj))
{
    $medicationItem[] = $row[0];
    $i++;
}
echo "Number of Rows: " . $i;
```

If you just want the number of rows i would suggest using the first method.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

You can wrote your code like below

```
$medicationItem = array();
$medicationItemSql = "SELECT medication FROM medication";
$medicationItemObj = mysqli_query($connection, $medicationItemSql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($medicationItemObj)) 
{
    echo $row['medication'];
}
```

I think this you want

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use the object oriented version of this and always use prepared statements!

```
//prepare SELECT statement
$medicationItemSQL=$connection->prepare("SELECT medication FROM medication");
// execute statement
$medicationItemSQL->execute();
//bind results to a variable
$medicationItemSQL->bind_result($medication);
//fetch data
$medicationItemSQL->fetch();
//close statement
$medicationItemSQL->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_fetch_assoc() as below.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($medicationItemObj)) {
   echo $row['medication'];
}
```